# How to pass three variable to custom template tag?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-filter

I am trying to pass 3 variables to my custom filter, but I can’t do it. Is there any such possibility in Django?

```
{{ item.cost|pay_blago:'{{item.can_pay_blago_to_currency}}, {{item.rest}}'}}

@register.filter
def pay_blago(cost, args):
    print(args.split(','))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django only allows one parameter. You can send it as a list/tuple and split it inside the filter.

There is a ticket for that too with (wontfix flag)
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1199

Answer (score 0):

If you are needing somethinf that's a function of an `Item` instance, the easiest way is a property defined on `Item`. In the Template, say,

```
{{item.cost_pay_blago}}
```

and on the `Item` model

```
# this is needed by template foo/bar.html
@property
def cost_pay_blago( self):

    result = # some value based on self.cost, self.rest and self.can_pay_blago_to_currency
    return  result
```

if `item` is not a model instance or if the function brings together data from multiple objects, you probably compute it in the view and put it into the context that you render the template against.

Or you could use the Jinja template engine, but that's a very big hammer to use if it's a small nut.